# What differences exist, if any, between touch and desktop Internet Explorer version numbering?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, internet-explorer

A typical installation of Windows 8.1 will have two editions of Internet Explorer: one for touch and one for the desktop. When Microsoft chooses *version numbers* for Internet Explorer, are they identical for both editions? Can a user gain information about both editions by simply looking at the version number for one?

Comment: A motivation for my question is wondering whether it is possible to get updates that update one edition to the current version while the other edition remains out-of-date.

Comment: If updates install correctly, the two experiences should theoretically remain in sync.  However, there is no documented promise that the two version numbers will always be consistent.  Many of the binaries are shared, so the risk of separation is low; however, it is not zero.  Documentation for [changes is available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn798774(v=vs.85).aspx), however, it's organized by the KB number associated with the update, rather than the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Both IE version are the same file `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`, so they have the same file version.